Store the Value of DatePicker and TimePicker Control in a SQLite Database and then Retrieve It
I wish to let a user pick a time and then store that time in my SQLite database. The problem I am having is SQLite doesn't support the datetimeoffset format which the DatePicker/TimePicker control uses.
So what be the best way to handle this? I was thinking of converting it to another format but I don't want to lose any data. I need to to be able to store it in the database and then retrieve it and put it back into a DatePicker/TimePicker control. I am using WinUi 3 with Entity Framework Core.
Xaml
<DatePicker x:Name="StartDatePicker"  Header="Start Date" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" />
<TimePicker x:Name="StartTimePicker"  Header="Start Time" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"/>
<DatePicker x:Name="EndDatePicker"  Header="End Date"  Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" />
<TimePicker x:Name="EndTimePicker"  Header="End Time" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"/>

Code Behind Page
 public AddShiftDialog()
 {
this.InitializeComponent();

Binding startDateBinding = new Binding();
startDateBinding.Source = Shift;
startDateBinding.Path = new PropertyPath("StartDateTemp");
startDateBinding.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
startDateBinding.UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged;
BindingOperations.SetBinding(StartDatePicker, DatePicker.DateProperty, startDateBinding);

Binding endDateBinding = new Binding();
endDateBinding.Source = Shift;
endDateBinding.Path = new PropertyPath("EndDateTemp");
endDateBinding.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
endDateBinding.UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged;
BindingOperations.SetBinding(EndDatePicker, DatePicker.DateProperty, endDateBinding);

Binding startTimeBinding = new Binding();
startTimeBinding.Source = Shift;
startTimeBinding.Path = new PropertyPath("StartTimeTemp");
startTimeBinding.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
startTimeBinding.UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged;
BindingOperations.SetBinding(StartTimePicker, TimePicker.TimeProperty, startTimeBinding);

Binding endTimeBinding = new Binding();
endTimeBinding.Source = Shift;
endTimeBinding.Path = new PropertyPath("EndTimeTemp");
endTimeBinding.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
endTimeBinding.UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged;
BindingOperations.SetBinding(EndTimePicker, TimePicker.TimeProperty, endTimeBinding);
}

Model
public partial class Shift: BaseModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }               

    [ObservableProperty]
    private DateTimeOffset _startDate;

    [ObservableProperty]
    private DateTimeOffset _endDate;

    [ObservableProperty]
    private DateTimeOffset _startTime;

    [ObservableProperty]
    private DateTimeOffset _endTime;

[NotMapped]
public DateTimeOffset StartDateTemp
{
    get
    {
        if(StartDate == string.Empty)
        {
            return DateTimeOffset.Now; 
        }                
        return DateTimeOffset.Parse(StartDate);
    }
    set
    {
        StartDate = value.ToString();
    }
}

[NotMapped]
public DateTimeOffset EndDateTemp
{
    get
    {
        if (EndDate == string.Empty)
        {
            return DateTimeOffset.Now;
        }
        return DateTimeOffset.Parse(EndDate);
    }
    set
    {
        EndDate = value.ToString();
    }
}

[NotMapped]
public DateTimeOffset StartTimeTemp
{
    get
    {
        if (StartTime == string.Empty)
        {
            return DateTimeOffset.Now;
        }
        return DateTimeOffset.Parse(StartTime);
    }
    set
    {
        StartTime = value.ToString();
    }
}

[NotMapped]
public DateTimeOffset EndTimeTemp
{
    get
    {
        if (EndTime == string.Empty)
        {
            return DateTimeOffset.Now;
        }
        return DateTimeOffset.Parse(EndTime);
    }
    set
    {
        EndTime = value.ToString();
    }
}
}


You may use DateTimeOffset.ToString and DateTimeOffset.Parse Method or System.Text.Json, more customization, for serializing and deserializing. See DateTime and DateTimeOffset support in System.Text.Json for more information.

I've updated my code to give a better idea of what I am trying to achieve.

Did you mean your code had utilized DateTimeOffset.ToString and DateTimeOffset.Parse Method? Do they lose any data?

Well no I just added those after you suggested it.  But I am not sure how to bind it because I need to convert it from string and then bind it to the TimePicker and then when saving to Database do the opposite and convert it back to string.

Try preparing the data before this.InitializeComponent();. and use Shift in XAML.

You can bind the string property and use a value converter. For example:
public class StringToDateTimeOffsetConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        if (value is string stringValue)
        {
            return DateTimeOffset.Parse(stringValue);
        }

        return DateTimeOffset.MinValue;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        if (value is DateTimeOffset dateTimeOffset)
        {
            return dateTimeOffset.ToString();
        }

        return string.Empty;
    }
}

<Page.Resources>
    <local:StringToDateTimeOffsetConverter x:Key="StringToDateTimeOffsetConverter" />
</Page.Resources>

<DatePicker SelectedDate="{x:Bind ViewModel.StartDate, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Converter={StaticResource StringToDateTimeOffsetConverter}}" />


Preparing the data in the constructor rather than before this.InitializeComponent();. You can see it in the document code, Initializing a date value.
I also test it and all work.
public sealed partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    string text = "ABC";
    DateTimeOffset myelectedDate = DateTimeOffset.Now;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        text = "DEF";
        myelectedDate = myelectedDate.AddYears(1);
        this.InitializeComponent();
        myelectedDate = myelectedDate.AddYears(1);
        text = "GHI";
    }
}

XAML
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
    <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind text}"></TextBlock>
    <DatePicker SelectedDate="{x:Bind myelectedDate}"></DatePicker>
</StackPanel>

